# Service resolution doesn't work in minikube

Tags: kubernetes

I installed minikube to use kubernetes locally. I was able to create pods and services locally.

However, pods (and containers) running on them, cannot resolve services using service names.

Example: I have redis service running that acts a proxy for redis pods.

`kubectl get services` shows taht redis service has been created.

However, when my web application tries to connect to `redis-service`, I get connection timeout, because web application (pod) cannot resolve `redis-service`.

Is there anything special taht needs to be installed to get service resolution working locally.

this is the output of running `kubectl get services`

```
 frontend            10.0.0.250                 80/TCP      3h
 kubernetes          10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP     3h
 redis-service       10.0.0.156   <none>        6379/TCP    3h
 rethinkdb-service   10.0.0.89    <none>        28015/TCP   3h






kubectl describe services --namespace=kube-system

Name:                   kube-dns
Namespace:              kube-system
Labels:                 k8s-app=kube-dns,kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS
Selector:               <none>
Type:                   ClusterIP
IP:                     10.0.0.10
Port:                   dns     53/UDP
Endpoints:              10.0.2.15:53
Port:                   dns-tcp 53/TCP
Endpoints:              10.0.2.15:53
Session Affinity:       None
No events.

Name:                   kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:              kube-system
Labels:                 app=kubernetes-dashboard,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
Selector:               app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                   NodePort
IP:                     10.0.0.156
Port:                   <unset> 80/TCP
NodePort:               <unset> 30000/TCP
Endpoints:              172.17.0.2:9090
Session Affinity:       None
No events.
```

Comment: What does the output of `kubectl describe services --namespace=kube-system` look like? Is there a healthy `kube-dns` service running?

Comment: Name:                   kube-dns
Namespace:              kube-system
Labels:                 k8s-app=kube-dns,kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS
Selector:               <none>
Type:                   ClusterIP
IP:                     10.0.0.10
Port:                   dns     53/UDP
Endpoints:              10.0.2.15:53
Port:                   dns-tcp 53/TCP
Endpoints:              10.0.2.15:53
Session Affinity:       None
No events.

Comment: Yes there is a kube-dns running

Comment: If you run "nslookup redis-service" from inside your pod, what is the output?

Comment: Same issue. `kubectl describe services --namespace=kube-system` shows kube-dns running. I do `minikube ssh` and get this: 

`
    docker@boot2docker:~$ nslookup atalanta-service
    Server:    192.168.64.1
    Address 1: 192.168.64.1
    
    nslookup: can't resolve 'atalanta-service'
`

Comment: Works after I create a pod as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/114) and then do: $ kubectl exec -it busybox nslookup kubernetes
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10

Name:      kubernetes
Address 1: 10.0.0.1

So it is running after all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose your services as `type: NodePort` in minikube instead of `ClusterIP`

You can then access them with `minikube service <servicename>`

(or you can find out which port they were mapped manually to with `kubectl get services`)